# Indy 10 TidTCPServer encoding characters

Tags: delphi-xe2, indy10, tcpserver

Indy 10 Sockets . TIdTCPServer component . There is a client program that connects to a server program using sockets. Everything working , there is no trouble in communicating , but I can not send a string with special characters from the server to the client. When sending a string like this:

```
         AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn ( ' Usuário não existe' ) ;
```

Client receives the string :

usu?rio n?o existe

Anyone who has ever worked with this component knows how do I set the encoding correctly and to send this special string to the client ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, Indy uses 7bit ASCII as its character encoding (for compatibility with various Internet protocols).  To use a different character encoding, you need to either:

1. set the `IOHandler.DefStringEncoding` property before doing any reading/writing.  The string-based I/O methods will then use this encoding by default.

   ```pascal
   // note: use TIdTextEncoding.UTF8 if not using Indy 10.6 or later...
   AContext.Connection.IOHandler.DefStringEncoding := IndyTextEncoding_UTF8;
   ```
2. use the optional `AByteEncoding` parameter of the various string-based I/O methods, including `WriteLn()`.

   ```pascal
   // note: use TIdTextEncoding.UTF8 if not using Indy 10.6 or later...
   AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('Usuário não existe', IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
   ```

Needless to say, the client will also have to use an equivalent encoding when reading the server's data so it can decode the transmitted bytes back to Unicode.  For example:

```pascal
// note: use TIdTextEncoding.UTF8 if not using Indy 10.6 or later...
Client.IOHandler.DefStringEncoding := IndyTextEncoding_UTF8;
```

Or:

```pascal
// note: use TIdTextEncoding.UTF8 if not using Indy 10.6 or later...
S := Client.IOHandler.ReadLn(IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
```

Comment: Results after :
             AContext.Connection.IOHandler.DefStringEncoding := TIdTextEncoding.ASCII;

Usuario nao existe


Results after :
             AContext.Connection.IOHandler.DefStringEncoding := TIdTextEncoding.ANSI;

Usu?rio n?o existe



not solved . which encoding should I use?

Comment: Thank U. My mistakes were 2, the client was not using the equivalent Encoding to read, and second I should use UTF8 and not ASCII or ANSI. Now worked perfectly. Thanks again !!!!